# Retrieving unique IDs with an associated Media ID

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find unique User Id's with and associated Media Id.

Here is what I have:

```
Select UserId, (Select Top(1) MediaId From Media Where UserId = M.UserId ORder By NewId()) as MediaId  From Media as M Group By UserId
```

I tried different group by combinations, but none of them worked.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**

The table looks like this:

```
MediaId int PK
UserId  int FK
Status  nvarchar(50)
```

Expected results

```
   UserId  MediaId
     9    101
    10    234
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you require. Can you provide table structures, data and expected results?

Comment: Is UserId unique throughout the table? Is MediaId unique throughout the table? Are UserId and MediaId unique if taken together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to consider a two step process i.e. creation of a work table that would have the unique userid and a column for the mediaid. You can then use a loop to set the top mediaid for each user.